# Does removing my nvidia graphics drivers disable my ubuntu GUI?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

Context:
I am currently trying to get CUDA-8.0 to work on ubuntu 14.04 while previous versions of CUDA were already installed. This is a very careful balancing act, where the right steps need to be taken in the right order. Unfortunately I failed. This leaves me with undescriptive errors and no obvious way to solve them.
The standard way to solve these problems is of course: reinstall the OS and try again. However that has obvious disadvantages as well.

Problem:
I need to remove anything remotely related to CUDA and nvidia to be able to retry installing CUDA-8.0. This includes any graphics drivers. However graphics drivers are potentially important for the workings of my OS (Ubuntu 14.04). How should I approach deleting nvidia drivers without bricking my computer?
The command I am hesitant to use is:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

Comment: Did you consider using the nouveau driver while you are replacing the Nvidia ones?

Comment: I am afraid that this will give extra conflicts with the nvidia drivers, do you know how well nvidia works with nouveau?

Comment: The question you should be asking is whether or not `nouveau` will work with your card for the brief period before installing nvidia drivers again. If it works in a live session chances are it will also be fine in the installed system. If not, just use `nomodeset`until the proprietary drivers are installed. And if you're going to reinstall consider first a newer release like 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I spend some time working on a different computer, postponing switching GPU drivers. Then I came across this post:
https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1000667/cuda-setup-and-installation/failed-to-initialize-nvml-driver-library-version-mismatch/
Purging cuda and deleting any cuda files left in /usr/local/cuda, /usr/local/cuda-7-5 etc. and then reinstalling cuda-8.0 left me with the error:

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

This appeared to me as requiring me to uninstall the current driver and then install the correct driver. However as in the link, just using the 'nvidia-smi' command also gave this error. So just as in the link I tried restarting my computer (something I should do more often) and that worked!

I don't know whether restarting would have solved my problem earlier. But it was definitely part of the solution and I didn't have to do anything manually to the drivers.